# Replace value in multiple strings without charindex

Tags: sql, replace, charindex

so This is a sample of my DB Values

[image]

```
UPDATE page p SET p.content = REPLACE(p.content, SUBSTRING(p.content, CHARINDEX('php?id=', p.content) +1), CONCAT('php?id=',p.course)) WHERE p.content LIKE '%php?id=%' AND p.content NOT LIKE CONCAT('%','php?id=',p.course,'%');
```

I'm Trying to only get the text after php?id= which is a number and change it to the correct number which is the course column

so for example the first value should be changed to

```
4|Enjoy your training!<a href="*/view.php?id=4">
```

Unfortunately charindex keeps giving me an Error

Any Help on how to Make this thing work without charindex as i Believe our server does not support this function

[image]

UPDATE: Charindex didnt exist in mysql so i had to use LOCATE fuction instead. Also i wasnt using the root password for the whole server, just the root password for the db

Thanks for the heads up!

Now just need the query to correctly update... as it removes just everything after  <a href etc etc and doesnt replace

Comment: Who manages the DB? You need execute permission on that server.

Comment: I'm in the IT Department I have the root password for db and using that in HeidiSQL to enter the database

Comment: Can you take the DBMS?